# Record keystrokes through ssh and be able to replay them

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, keyboard, recording

I've been working on a small script today for our minimal server here where I can log into our inventory software, download the csv and put it into the web directory using a cron job periodically.

Using script and scriptreplay I was able to get all this working perfectly, until I realized that scriptreplay was literally replaying the terminal output as opposed to the actual website I was loading using w3m the first time.

So I'm looking for a way to record keystrokes via ssh in order to follow my initial instructions.

Does anyone have any ideas? Failing that, does anyone have any alternatives? It's only a mini version of Ubuntu our server is running so no GUI.

Comment: What you need is create a script, not exactly "replaying commands". https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a lot of back and forth with [Caleb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1925/caleb) we've finally come up with a solution to the problem. The login i was trying to do straight to the inventory management software was fiddly, but to quote as per our back and forward conversations tonight, this solved it. No need for recording keystrokes at all. Just good old noggin usage.

> The first connection in your script is to login and create a session in a cookie:

`curl -s -c cookiejar.txt -b cookiejar.txt -L -d 'username=user@example.com&pass=******' -e 'https://my.channelgrabber.com/login.php' https://my.channelgrabber.com/login.php -o /dev/null`

> Next you can ask for another page, but you have to pass the previous one you were on. For example after the above, you can run:

`curl -s -c cookiejar.txt -b cookiejar.txt -L -e 'https://my.channelgrabber.com/index.php' https://my.channelgrabber.com/products.php -o products.html`

Doing this brought about what i needed perfectly. From here, i just deleted the cookie once it had been used and retrieved what i needed:

`rm -rf cookiejar.txt`

...and set it on a cron job to run every 5 minutes. There's some extra lines i did regarding the full function but this right here is what fixed everything for me. It was a lot of trial and error. A big thank you again to [Caleb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1925/caleb) who helped me with this whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others that there may be better ways for you to approach your problem, but I can see some benefits in recording what you do and use that to later make a script.

To track your input, you could pass it through `tee` which would output it to a file such as:

```
tee logFile < /dev/stdin | bash
```

You can close it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Recording commands and replaying them is the wrong way to tackle this problem. Instead you should be writing a script that handles this job. Shell scripts are basically just lists of commands like you would run on the command line in order that they will execute. Start a new black plain text file in your editor and on the first line enter what shell you want it to run in. For example this should be a good start:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
```

Now save that with some name like `fetch_and_post_logs.bash`. Note this should be some place where `cron` can find it, `/usr/local/bin/` might be a good choice.

Next, set the script to be executable:

```
$ chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/fetch_and_post_logs.bash
```

Now lets flesh that script out a little bit. For this part you'll have to supply some know how yourself, but lets say you start by copying something from a remote server to a local folder:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

timestamp=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

scp user@remotehost:/path/to/logs.csv /path/to/www/logs-${timestamp}.csv
```

Then from cron, run this script:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/fetch_and_post_logs.bash
```

This should get you started. If you need more help please ask specific questions about the places you get stuck.

Note for this to work `cron` will need to be able to login as the user in question without a password, so you'll want to setup a user that has limited access to just the logs and then add a public/private key par so that it can authenticate.

Comment: This is a very good example of what i -wish- i could do. Unfortunately the CSV i need to update from the inventory software isn't accessable outside of logging into it, and even then it's put through a php script on their end before i can download it. The reason behind duplicating my keystrokes was to allow me to open up w3m and replicate me logging in, putting in the php url for the csv, saving the csv and logging out. Hence it's so backwards.

Comment: @DanielRuxton Don't despair, `w3m` isn't the tool for this, but you can write a script using a a series of `curl` commands. First request the login page, and save the cookies in a cookie  jar file. Now add `--data` strings with your login information, passing the same cookie jar file to curl to login. Now that you're logged in, download your log files with another curl command, again using the same cookie jar.

Comment: I looked into curl early on but wasn't 100% sure on where to even start with it in regards to logging in. I didn't think of the cookie jar. Let me see if i can get this working..

Comment: By the way the thing that you _thought_ you wanted is called `expect` and allows you to pass key events into programs that aren't designed to be scripted, wait for things to appear on screen, then send more keys, etc. But please trust me on this one you don't actually  want to go down that road in this case. There might be hurdles but you will end up with a better solution doing this the right way round rather than backwards.

Comment: Your input is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: i've tried this line: `curl -c mycookie "https://my.channelgrabber.com" -d "loginUID=login@email.co.uk" -d "loginPWD=password" --referer "https:// my.channelgrabber.com"` There's no confirmation back from curl. Afterwards i try to access the page in question and export contents using `curl o- example.csv http://my.channelgrabber.co m/ajax/product_export.php` but it's returning an "unable to resolve host". Meaning, i'm assuming, an authentication failure. (im obviously using the correct email and pass for login)

Comment: adding the -v argument brings up [this](http://pastebin.com/4eDBFny5) upon execution... so i'm assuming the cookies are at least setting correctly.

Comment: @DanielRuxton Your second curl needs  `-c mycokie` as well. Also you probably mean `https` in the second one since you did that in the first one. Lastly the `m` got separated from `com`. That's your "can't resolve host" error.

Comment: Also note that pastebin has the cookie data that (may) allow others to login to this device without your password, make sure you reset the device or logout all users or to something to invalidate that session so you don't get hacked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52373/discussion-between-caleb-and-daniel-ruxton).

Answer (score 1):

Let the computer record the commands and write the beginnings of the script for you. This is trivial with [TCL](http://antirez.com/articoli/tclmisunderstood.html), in particular `expect`.

```
$ autoexpect ssh somesystem
autoexpect started, file is script.exp
Last login: Mon Jan 23 15:14:04 2017 from 84-182-91-4.dyn.example.net
somesystem$ pwd
/home/jdoe
somesystem$ exit
logout
Connection to 192.0.2.42 closed.
autoexpect done, file is script.exp
$ cat script.exp
...
```

Or regular scripting, that's easy too.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
package require Tcl 8.5

set timestamp [clock format [clock seconds] -format "%Y-%m-%d"]

exec scp user@host:/in/log.csv /out/log-$timestamp.csv
```

Need to interact with a `spawn` following the automation? That's what `interact` is for. Password prompts? No great difficulty to automate with `expect`.

Comment: I've written 100s of expect scripts and they can be really powerful ways to get things done. In this case they are what this OP _thought_ they were looking for. That being said I think recommending `expect` for anything should always come with a caveat that if there is a more straight forward method of access it should always be preferred. The `expect` solution to use a console browser to will almost always be more brittle and difficult to repair later than an API call with a script for example. In this case that's all the OP actually needed to do: authenticate and download a CSV file.